# Getting the document of external url with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an html form that accepts a url as a txt input and a submit button. When I click on the button I want to access the document model of the provided url.

How can I get access to the document of that url using javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make a HTTP GET request to the url, you will receive the document as a response. When you type in a URL on a web browser, it is basically making this GET request, getting the response document, and rendering it nicely for you.

On your HTML file, with Javascript, you can use XMLHttpRequest to make the HTTP GET request. [Here is a tutorial from MDN on how to use XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest). You may also find it easier to use [jQuery's GET function](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) to achieve this.